# Not able to submit form second time in a row in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making a registration/login system in a mern app and i am facing a problem , the thing is whenever i register for the first time it works perfectly i get redirected to verification page submit my otp there and then get redirected to the home page (login/register page) but the problem is after coming to this page if i try to register again with diffrent credentials it neither redirect me to the verification page nor i see anything happening in my backend , only one thing happens that is my page reloads and all the creds that i entered get added in my url like this : - http://localhost:3000/?first_name=somename&second_name=somesecondname&email=try@gmail.com&new_password=password123&date=2022-01-29&gender=Male
here is my code which is related to it:-
JSX:-

```
const postregister = async(e)=>{
        
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        const {first_name,second_name,email,new_password, date , gender} = userregister;

        const res = await fetch('/register',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                first_name,second_name,email,new_password, date , gender
            }),
            
        })

        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)
        if(data.status === 201){
            Navigate(`/verify/${first_name}/${email}`);
        }

        else if(data.status === 202){
            setshowalert({...showalert, bool:'true',text:data.message,removealert:'false'})
        }

        else{
            console.log('something went wrong')
        }
        

    const handleregister = (e)=>{
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setuserregister({...userregister,[name]:value})
        console.log(value)

    }
```

Edit - I have found out that if I wait for 1 minute or maybe 30 seconds before submitting the next form my form gets submitted but it doesn't get submitted if I try to submit it right after I am redirected to the register page

Comment: Did you clear the form fields once submitted the form?

Comment: No , How am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If everything works, when you wait some time before sending next form and does not work when you do it instantly, there is possibilty that the firt request have no time to be served.

I often fix it in this way:

1. Add new variable, like `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);`
2. At the begging of sending-request function set state to `true`
3. After response arrive (before redirect or setting errors) set state to `false`
4. Set form's submit button to enable / disable depending of `loading` state

It prevent user to send next request, before the first one is not finished.

Comment: But isn't it already at the start of the function?

Comment: I have added something in my question please read it

Comment: Ok, now I see how it's build, the second function is handle to inputs only :)

Comment: Thanks for this , but how can i solve this problem of time? i mean if i deploy this and some users try to register at same time , that would cause a problem right?

Comment: It won't make confilict, because your app is client-side, what means every user has his kind of 'local copy' on his device. My method prevents sending several requests at the same time from single device, but it do not stop sending requests from different devices at the same time.

Comment: Ohh thats how it works , there is sure a lot of things in web development other than the coding part

Comment: is my answer solved the problem?